# How to use flask render_template inside a MoinMoin macro?

Tags: flask, moinmoin

I'm new to MoinMoin and flask. I have a moinmoin site using python macros. For the moment, I just use some basic string format method to return html from my macro. I would like to use the flask templates with the `render_template` method. It doesn't work for now, because the context stack seems to be empty. I don't really know what is the good way of making it work. Should i create a context with flask by giving to it the macro object itself or the macro request ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a macro you are most likely using a [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) [macro](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) (Python doesn't have macros).  In that case you can use the [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) or [`import`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import) directives to load other Jinja templates and render them.

Comment: I was using moinmoin macros, but yes the solution was to render directly the jinja templates and not to use flask. Thank's!